# Removing xmlns, SOAP:Envelope, SOAP:Body, from xml using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I am using XSLT to transform the xml response in my project.I have the following xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" SOAP:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <SOAP:Body>
      <response:performJobResponse xmlns:response="http://tempuri.org/" SOAP:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <whiteboard>
            <PQ>
               <SOAP:Envelope SOAP:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
                  <SOAP:Body>
                     <response:performJobResponse SOAP:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
                        <whiteboard>
                           <PQ>
                              <SOAP:Envelope SOAP:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
                                 <SOAP:Body>
                                    <performJob loadfromcache="yes">
                                       <jobName>PQIssueUpdate</jobName>
                                       <whiteboard>
                                          <PQ>
                                             <PQContact>
                                                <userID>Test</userID>
                                                <password>Test@2</password>
                                             </PQContact>
                                             <workflowStatusComment>
                                                <comment>Issue released.  Routing Status changed from CATCHALL to Pharmancy.  Issue updated by user DT76747.</comment>
                                             </workflowStatusComment>
                                          </PQ>
                                       </whiteboard>
                                       <requestNodeName>//PQ</requestNodeName>
                                       <responseNodeName>//PQ</responseNodeName>
                                       <jobDB>
                                          <name>PQCustomerService</name>
                                          <userID>sa</userID>
                                          <password>password</password>
                                       </jobDB>
                                    </performJob>
                                 </SOAP:Body>
                                 <response>
                                    <DST xml:lang="en-US">
                                       <jobName version="1.0">SRVChangeLock</jobName>
                                       <trace>0</trace>
                                       <readable>N</readable>
                                       <AWD>
                                          <userID>DT76747</userID>
                                          <password>Removed for security purposes</password>
                                          <transaction id="2016-07-07-02.02.19.127220T01">
                                             <createTime time="Y">2016-07-07T02:02:19:127220-05:00</createTime>
                                             <assignedTo>DT76747</assignedTo>
                                             <lockedBy>DT76747</lockedBy>
                                             <customScreen>WRKXMPL</customScreen>
                                             <workflow route="Status">
                                                <workStep status="_NEXT" next="Y" />
                                             </workflow>
                                          </transaction>
                                       </AWD>
                                       <jobVersion>1.0</jobVersion>
                                       <jobReturn jobName="SRV00017">
                                          <taskName />
                                          <description />
                                          <value>0</value>
                                       </jobReturn>
                                    </DST>
                                 </response>
                              </SOAP:Envelope>
                           </PQ>
                        </whiteboard>
                     </response:performJobResponse>
                  </SOAP:Body>
                  <response>
                     <DST xml:lang="en-US">
                        <jobName version="1.0">SRVObjectUpdate</jobName>
                        <trace>0</trace>
                        <readable>N</readable>
                        <AWD>
                           <userID>DT76747</userID>
                           <password>Removed for security purposes</password>
                           <transaction id="2016-07-07-02.02.19.127220T01" workSelected="false" hasChildWork="N" children="N" hasParent="Y" hasParentCase="Y" hasChildSource="N">
                              <id>2016-07-07-02.02.19.127220T01</id>
                           </transaction>
                        </AWD>
                     </DST>
                  </response>
               </SOAP:Envelope>
            </PQ>
         </whiteboard>
         <jobReturn>
            <value>0</value>
         </jobReturn>
      </response:performJobResponse>
   </SOAP:Body>
</SOAP:Envelope>
```

I want to remove all the `xmlns` content,`SOAP:Envelope`, `<SOAP:Body>` and `<response>`tag related content.

My final xml should be as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PQ>
   <PQContact>
      <userID>Test</userID>
      <password>Test@2</password>
   </PQContact>
   <workflowStatusComment>
      <comment>Issue released.  Routing Status changed from CATCHALL to Pharmancy.  Issue updated by user DT76747.</comment>
   </workflowStatusComment>
</PQ>
```

Could you please help me out?

Comment: It would be great if people let me know why they are down voting so that I can correct myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try this transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:response="http://tempuri.org/">

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">  
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//SOAP:Body/performJob//whiteboard/node()"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That's perfect!.. +1 for quick solution.